# Is it possible to share environment variables between two react app running along with?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I have a small project, a chart **app A**, that need to embedded into an web **app B**. They are both React app.

App A will need an env variable called `WS_ENDPOINT_URL` to open a connection to websocket. After building app A into bundle, and embedded into web app B. The way of embedding is:

- Import A bundle file into a React component
- Create Chart instance, then call method to render it on the web app B

so I wonder how could I input `WS_ENDPOINT_URL` for A bundle to work?

Is there any way to share env variable from app B to app A? like from parent to child?

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: It depends on how you embed it

Comment: @欧阳斌 We import the bundle js into a React Component, then initialize the Chart instance, and call the some method to make the chart rendered

Comment: if app b is used as component , WS_ENDPOINT_URL can pass as a prop to app b, 

like `<AppB url={process.env. WS_ENDPOINT_URL} />`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, but you have to use some kind of Secrets Manager like **Doppler** https://www.doppler.com/

Answer (score 0):

Give me a lil bit more context here.

- are both apps created with create-react-app ?
  --  If yes you need to create an .env file on each project with the same variables such as `WS_ENDPOINT_URL`
- those the embedded app needs to be an app ?
  --  If not why not instead of been an app why not a component create a component publish it and import it as dependency
  ?

Tell me more of the building process how is it done and I can help u